# How do you modify form data before saving it while using Django's CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm using the `CreateView` of Django and I'm trying to find out how I can modify any text which gets sent before it gets saved. For example, right now I'm only looking to lowercase all the text before saving.

I know I need to use `form_valid()` but I can't seem to get it right.

**forms.py**

```
class ConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Config
        fields = ["heading", "name", "data", "rating"]
```

**views.py**

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    super().form_valid(form)
    form.fields["heading"].lower()
    form.fields["name"].lower()
    form.fields["data"].lower()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That shouldn't be done in form_valid. You should do that in the form itself. Instead of letting CreateView automatically create a form for you, do it explicitly and overwrite the `clean` method.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = MyModel
      fields = ('list', 'of', 'fields')

   def clean(self):
       for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
           self.cleaned_data['field'] = value.lower()
```

...

```
class MyCreateView(views.CreateView):
    form_class = MyForm
```

Answer (score 3):

Override `get_form_kwargs` method to update the `kwargs` which instantiates the form.

**Solution**:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    # update super call if python < 3
    form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    form_kwargs['data']['str_field_name'] = form_kwargs['data']['str_field_name'].lower()

    return form_kwargs
```

**Ref**:
[get_form_kwargs docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

While it may not be the nicest solution, it can be done like this:

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    # ...
    self.object.save()

    return http.HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record

In the first case

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    # update super call if python < 3
    form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    form_kwargs['data']['str_field_name'] = form_kwargs['data'['str_field_name'].lower()
    return form_kwargs
```

Django complains "This QueryDict instance is immutable". And workaround is

```
 data = kwargs['data'].copy() # mutable copy
 data['foo'] = 'whatever' #supply the missing default value
 kwargs['data'] = data
```